# How to make a fill parent+wrap_content (in that order) Android

Tags: java, android, layout

I'll try to simplify the problem for avoiding long code pieces: I want to do something like that in my layout

[image: Target]

The structure should be easy with something like:

```
 LinearLayoutA (vertical)
      LinearLayoutB (vertical)
           LinearLayoutC    (horizontal)
           LinearLayoutC'   (horizontal)
      LinearLayoutB' (vertical)
           LinearLayoutC''  (horizontal)
           LinearLayoutC''' (horizontal)
  All with weight=1
```

the problem for me is define what to put within the LinearLayoutC. So focusing now the elements inside LinearLayoutC:

My first option was another LinearLayout (vertical) the problem is that if the image is taller than the LinearLayoutC the TextView is not visible.

So I used that RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Eiffel"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
    ></TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/eiffel2"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_above="@id/text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Nice it works! But not for long =(. (We will call it from now RelativeLayout1) When the screen is smaller than the views the layout seems perfect but when going into a larger screen the block is aligned to the bottom of the parent and I'd like it to be centered in the screen (or the sublayout). Like shows that screen:

[image: Problem]

That is because of the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" at the TextView.

Trying to solve that I used a RelativeLayout2 for wrap the RelativeLayout1 with a code like:

```
<RelativeLayout2
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

     <RelativeLayout1
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      .....
     ></RelativeLayout1>

 </RelativeLayout2>
```

But even with that the layout RelativeLayout1 still aligned to the bottom of the image (and filling all the screen vertically as it had a height= fill_parent and I don't understand why is that happening and how can I solve it. Please can you help me? I've tried for hours. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add
 `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your ImageView

Answer (score 1):

remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the textview and add this to your root relativelayout tag `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: Doing that the text goes to the top of the layout and the image disappears =(

Answer (score 0):

I had debug your code .. try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity = "center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/eiffel2"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"

    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Eiffel"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking some time for trying it. This snippet works for high screen/layout size but when the image is bigger than the container the text disappears (and it should resize the image)

Comment: you can use scrollview for this...else you need to take care the iamge size as per screen size...

Comment: I cant use a scrollview, the 4 cells cant have a scrollview each. Are you sure there's no way of doing that?

Comment: you don't need to put scrollview for each cell ... add scrollview tag above the relative layout in above code....

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `TableLayout`? It is best suited for grid like views such as this one. You can even specify weights for different columns, etc. and have different column widths.

Comment: The problem is still what to put inside the table because when the screen is small the text disappears and when its big the layout is not centered

Answer (score 0):

use  **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** for your second RelativeLayout

Comment: The first is still sticked to the bottom :(

Answer (score 0):

set

```
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
```

in the ImageView and the TextView, and then use a LinearLayout (with gravity= center) as container and it work

Comment: In large screens the layout fills all the height and the text is not centered =(